# Create a string-capable Guava Splitter

Tags: java, regex, split, guava

I would like to create a Guava Splitter for Java that can handles Java strings as one block. For instance, I would like the following assertion to be true:

```
@Test
public void testSplitter() {
  String toSplit = "a,b,\"c,d\\\"\",e";
  List<String> expected = ImmutableList.of("a", "b", "c,d\"","e");

  Splitter splitter = Splitter.onPattern(...);
  List<String> actual = ImmutableList.copyOf(splitter.split(toSplit));

  assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

I can write the regex to find all the elements and don't consider the ',' but I can't find the regex that would act as a separator to be used with a Splitter.

If it's impossible, please just say so, then I'll build the list from the findAll regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like something you should use a CSV library such as [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) for. Separating values and handling cases like quoted blocks are what they're all about.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Guava feature request: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=412

Answer (score 4):

I've same problem (except no need to support escaping of quote character). I don't like to include another library for such simple thing. And then i came to idea, that i need a mutable CharMatcher. As with solution of Bart Kiers, it keeps quote character.

```
public static Splitter quotableComma() {
    return on(new CharMatcher() {
        private boolean inQuotes = false;

        @Override
        public boolean matches(char c) {
            if ('"' == c) {
                inQuotes = !inQuotes;
            }
            if (inQuotes) {
                return false;
            }
            return (',' == c);
        }
    });
}

@Test
public void testQuotableComma() throws Exception {
    String toSplit = "a,b,\"c,d\",e";
    List<String> expected = ImmutableList.of("a", "b", "\"c,d\"", "e");
    Splitter splitter = Splitters.quotableComma();
    List<String> actual = ImmutableList.copyOf(splitter.split(toSplit));
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, but I didn't even think about a new CharMatcher. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You *could* split on the following pattern:

```
\s*,\s*(?=((\\["\\]|[^"\\])*"(\\["\\]|[^"\\])*")*(\\["\\]|[^"\\])*$)
```

which might look (a bit) friendlier with the `(?x)` flag:

```
(?x)            # enable comments, ignore space-literals
\s*,\s*         # match a comma optionally surrounded by space-chars
(?=             # start positive look ahead
  (             #   start group 1
    (           #     start group 2
      \\["\\]   #       match an escaped quote or backslash
      |         #       OR
      [^"\\]    #       match any char other than a quote or backslash
    )*          #     end group 2, and repeat it zero or more times
    "           #     match a quote
    (           #     start group 3
      \\["\\]   #       match an escaped quote or backslash
      |         #       OR
      [^"\\]    #       match any char other than a quote or backslash
    )*          #     end group 3, and repeat it zero or more times
    "           #     match a quote
  )*            #   end group 1, and repeat it zero or more times
  (             #   open group 4
    \\["\\]     #     match an escaped quote or backslash
    |           #     OR
    [^"\\]      #     match any char other than a quote or backslash
  )*            #   end group 4, and repeat it zero or more times
  $             #   match the end-of-input
)               # end positive look ahead
```

But even in this commented-version, it still is a monster. In plain English, this regex could be explained as follows:

> *Match a comma that is optionally surrounded by space-chars, only when looking ahead of that comma (all the way to the end of the string!), there are zero or an even number of quotes while ignoring escaped quotes or escaped backslashes.*

So, after seeing this, you might agree with ColinD (I do!) that using some sort of a CSV parser is the way to go in this case.

Note that the regex above will leave the qoutes around the tokens, i.e., the string `a,b,"c,d\"",e` (as a literal: `"a,b,\"c,d\\\"\",e"`) will be split as follows:

```
a
b
"c,d\""
e
```

Comment: I've +1'd your answer because it does (nearly) exactly what I want using the tools I want, but for the sake of the readability, I've taken ColinD's answer. Anyway, very very nice stuff!

Comment: @ogregoire, I totally agree. I mainly posted it to show what a monstrous regex you'd end up with: such a beast should not be let out in the wild! :)

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @Rage-Steel 's answer a bit.

```
final static CharMatcher notQuoted = new CharMatcher() {
     private boolean inQuotes = false;

     @Override
     public boolean matches(char c) {
        if ('"' == c) {
        inQuotes = !inQuotes;
     }
     return !inQuotes;
};

final static Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.on(notQuoted.and(CharMatcher.anyOf(" ,;|"))).trimResults().omitEmptyStrings();
```

And then,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String toSplit = "a=b c=d,kuku=\"e=f|g=h something=other\"";

    List<String> sputnik = SPLITTER.splitToList(toSplit);
    for (String s : sputnik)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Pay attention to thread safety (or, to simplify - there isn't any)